# Improving query performance on unindexed column in MS Access table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a big old MS Access table with ~84 columns and ~280k rows.  Three of these columns are `LabNumber` (indexed), `HospitalNumber` (non-indexed), and `NHSNumber` (non-indexed).  I want to search `HospitalNumber` *and* `NHSNumber` for a term to retrieve the value of `LabNumber`.  It's a regularly used production database, so the table **must** stay *as is*.  Oh, and the database is being accessed over a network.  The query was *painfully* slow.

Using the wonderful power of regular expressions, I can work out which one of `NHSNumber` and `HospitalNumber` I need to look in.  Reducing it to only looking in one *or* the other has made it faster, but it's still taking 30 seconds on a good day, sometimes longer.

My question is this.  Is there any other tips or tricks that I can use to try and bring the execution time down to a more manageable level?  Welcome pragmatic solutions to it all, but bear in mind that the table **must not** be altered, and the existing database **will** be updated relatively regularly (let's say that the data being a day out isn't a big deal, but a week out definitely is)

## Edit

The query was requested, so here it is.  Unfortunately it's not that exciting:

```
SELECT [ConsID], [LabNumber], [HospitalNumber], [NHSNumber]
FROM Samples
WHERE [NHSNumber]="1234567890";
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why adding an index to the original table isn't an option. It doesn't change its functionality.

Comment: It might be helpful to see actual query.

Comment: @Parfait - it's not exciting - but there you go

Comment: @Andre - it stores patient data, and so there's a lot of regulations (correctly) in place regarding what can and cannot happen.  For what I'm doing, there is no

Comment: (mumbles about storing large volumes of sensitive data in an Access backend, I hope you have a good - and tested - backup system in place). -- Then there is nothing to optimize, Gustav's answer will be the only option.

Comment: Adding the index to backend table cannot affect the data sensitivity. If regulations state that "table structure cannot be changed", adding of index is not table structure change. Send official request to IT department about adding the index, they should do this if they understand what they are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot modify the existing table, copy it to a local table and apply index on the columns you search.

This can all be done by code which you can run when an update is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use VBA to open the table on startup and keep it open until the database is closed, it should improve the performance significantly.